# How do you parse and access the timestamp and reading in a JsonArray of arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, gson

I have a JsonObject that contains a JsonArray of arrays. I would like to parse it using Gson. The following is what the data looks like. I can use `JsonArray data = resourceObj.get("data").getAsJsonArray()` to get the outer array, but I m not sure how to access the inner array. My understanding is that to get something as a JsonArray it has to be in the form "xyz": [ something] or "xyz"=[something]

```
{
    "sid": "123456",
    "data": [
    [
      1595808000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1595894400,
      0
    ],
    [
      1595980800,
      0.0829
    ],
    [
      1596067200,
      0.0047
    ]
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `data` is an array of arrays.

E.g. the value of `data[2][1]` is `0.0829`.

What the second value of the inner array is, I don't know, but the first value looks like it is a Unix Timestamp.

E.g. value `1595980800` is `Wednesday, July 29, 2020 12:00:00 AM GMT`.

Comment: When i try to access data this is the exception i get: Array type expected; found: 'com.google.gson.JsonArray'

Comment: @experimentunit1998X There is not enough information in the question to answer that. If you had a question about that error, then create a new question, show the error you need help with, and show the code causing that error.

Comment: I meant that when I tried to access the inner arrays following what you said by data[i][j] to iterate through the whole data JsonArray, it does not let me do so, because it is a JsonArray, not a regular array. I wanted to ask how to access the inner arrays of the outer data JsonArray, and get the timestamp and readings

Comment: @experimentunit1998X You use the API of `JsonArray` to access the data in the array. Which part of using `JsonArray` is troubling you? You did read the [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html), right?

Comment: I was using the enhanced for loop to go over the outer loop, meaning that i was getting JsonElements, and I couldnt convert this JsonElement into Array. I m not sure if the answer i posted is a valid solution for these scenarios, but it seems like a quick fix

Comment: @experimentunit1998X You couldn't call `getAsJsonArray()` on the [`JsonElement`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html) to work with it as an array? Why not? What error did you get?

Comment: oh, I dont recall, but I think i previously tried to use getAsJsonArray() but got an error some time back. also, i thought that it must have key to a value to parse a JSON array, emphasis on the JSON. Let me quickly try it again to test it out.

Comment: weird. this is weird. I think i must have recalled wrongly. Using getAsJsonArray() on the jsonElement or the inner array works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Also: if you have a string to parse so not using actual JsonObject and having such a stable JSON you can declare a wrapping data class to make handling more convenient and perhaps more type safe.

So something like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public static class MyData {
    private Long sid;
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class DataItem extends ArrayList<Object> {
        public LocalDateTime getSomeLocalDateTime() {
            return Instant
                .ofEpochSecond(((Double)get(0)).longValue())
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .toLocalDateTime();
        }
        public Double getSomeDouble() {
            return (Double)get(1);
        }
    }
    private List<DataItem> data; 
}
```

Use:

```
MyData myData = getGson().fromJson(json, MyData.class);
LocalDateTime ldt = myData.getData().get(0).getDate();
Double dbl = myData.getData().get(0).getSomeDouble();
```